# HTML/JavaScript Conexão WebService C#

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, web-service

Estou tentando fazer uma conexão com o banco usando web service.

Cheguei a montar um exemplo onde criei as funções soma e multiplica no meu WebService, mas estou com dificuldade na hora de conectar meu (HTML/JavaScript) no meu WebService (C#).

Achei diversos exemplos na internet, mas nenhum deles conseguiu sanar minhas dúvidas, por este motivo decidi perguntar aqui para ver se alguém poderia me auxiliar a fazer essa comunicação do WebService com o meu HTML.

Eu preciso que o meu HTML e o meu Javascript fiquem separados de uma aplicação web pois pretendo utilizar *(após entender como funciona a comunicação)* phonegap para fazer solicitações para o banco e retornar os valores para o usuário.

Não sei se consegui ser muito claro, mas minha ideia é ter um app compilado no phonegap e nele acessar um webService para solicitar dados que vem do banco e carregá-los no app.

Comment: Do jeito que você explicou não ficou muito claro... chegou a fazer algum código?

Answer (score 1):

Independente da linguagem back-end utilizada para se comunicar com o JS/HTML você deve utilizar um serviço REST, ou seja sua aplicação deve devolver um JSON a qualquer requisição feita através do JS.

Vamos imaginar que seu webservice esteja configurado para receber SQL via query string (cuidado com os dados que são liberados por seu webservice por questões de segurança), então teremos algo mais ou menos assim:

```
http://webservice.meusite.com?query=SELECT%20*%20FROM%20user
(http://webservice.meusite.com?query=SELECT * FROM user)
```

acessando essa url seu serviço deve retornar algo como:

```
{
    users:[
        {
            nome: "João",
            email: "joao@gmail.com"
        },
        {
            nome: "maria",
            email: "maria@gmail.com"
        },
        {
            /*...*/
        },
    ]
}
```

Com o jQuery você fará em uma página http://webservice.meusite.com.br/teste.html:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://webservice.meusite.com?query=SELECT%20*%20FROM%20user",
    success : function(data){
        for(var i in data.users)
            console.log(data.users[i].nome);
    }
});
```

Veja a saída no console.

Caso vá utilizar a requisição `$.ajax`em um domínio diferente você deve utilizar JSONP

Comment: No caso estou usando C# como web service, mas quando consigo o response, recebo o seguinte erro :
    Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

Comment: Se o erro for de JS provavelmente é um caracter sendo impressão em lugar errado no JSON. Pode colar sua saída JSON no http://jsfiddle.net/ ?